# SET Options issue on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a table which has a persisted computed HashByte column. After the table is created when I try to insert data from CSV to that table it complains:

> **INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.**

Some of the columns in CSV has data more than 8000 length so before inserting data in table I have Set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF so that it does not complain about data truncation. This was working perfectly until there was a requirement to include computed column.

So the question is How can I keep persisted computed column and at same time Set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF property enabled?

Code:

```
Create table dbo.demo
(
 [UniqueID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 Name varchar(50),
 Description varchar(max),  -- data truncation issue for this column
 HashValue as Hashbytes ('MD5' , CONCAT ('|', Name,Description))PERSISTED
 )

 insert into [dbo].[demo] (Name,Description)
 values ('John','<characters more than 8000>')
```

Comment: You can't; that's a case of "have your cake and eat it too". The engine enforces this setting so that it can make appropriate assumptions in the inner code dealing with computed columns. You will have to make sure things don't truncate -- for example, by explicitly truncating them yourself first. Alternatively, maintain the column value with a trigger rather than as a computed column. Relying on any of the ANSI settings being off is not a good idea -- these scenarios will only get less support moving forward.

Comment: Please share your table and your insert statement for us to check what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Truncation issue is not for the computed column. It is for other columns. And I don't want to truncate data. While loading data from CSV to table I want the same data and so while creating the table I have kept column type as varchar(max)

Comment: If the destination column is `VARCHAR(MAX)`, then the value should not be truncated -- that raises the question of how you're importing the CSV, because apparently whatever is doing that is not using a `MAX` type to process the data (but `VARCHAR(8000)`). If that was fixed, you wouldn't need to fudge `ANSI_WARNINGS`.

Comment: @Birel I have added code in my post.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Table is created first and then Csv data is loaded into that table. I am using ETL Tool talend where there in one of the components I was having this create and insert logic. Like I had said in my question it was working but moment i included computed column it started to complain.

Comment: The code as written has no problem with truncation -- string constants of more than 8000 characters work fine, as you can verify yourself. You should consult the Talend documentation (or open a new question) on how to correctly import/export to `MAX` types (assuming it has support at all). Any ETL tool worth its salt should support them, otherwise it's not a good match for SQL Server.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right in SQL server it works perfectly.After some searching I found this info: create a table with a persisted, computed column, the following connection settings must be enabled:

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

So that means I will have to keep ANSI WARNINGS ON if I have a computed column in my table. Because somehow talend is not allowing to insert rows greater than 8000 even if column type is varchar(max) if Ansi warnings is on

Comment: To quote `HASHBYTES`'s documentation *"For SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and earlier, allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes."*. You don't pass a `varchar(MAX)` in the version of SQL Server you have. This is where the truncation error is.

Comment: @Larnu Spot on! But then is there any other alternative for HashBytes which won't have this 8000 character limit issue. I know there is checksum but it again has its own limitations -  **If at least one of the values in the expression list changes, the list checksum will probably change. However, this is not guaranteed. Otherwise, consider using HashBytes instead. With a specified MD5 hash algorithm, the probability that HashBytes will return the same result, for two different inputs, is much lower compared to CHECKSUM.**